# How to efficiently create data on one variable all agents have

Tags: netlogo, agent

I'm working with a NetLogo model on EV charging behaviour. All (500) agents monitor their `my-charging-demand` per tick and I want to find out what happens to this emergent behaviour when I change the policy intervention that is active (costs of electricity in this case). I am trying to show changes in charging characteristics such as charging-duration, charging power etc.

What is the best way to create data on the agents' `my-charging-demand` in time?

Right now I am plotting all their data in one graph using the following code:

```
ask adopters 
 [ create-temporary-plot-pen (word-who)
   set-plot-pen-color color
   plotxy ticks my-charging-demand
 ]
```

It works, but unfortunately it also made the model incredibly slow, as 500 pens are to be updated every tick. The model needs 105120 ticks before a whole year/run is completed, as each tick in the model represents 5 minutes. Therefore, speed does matter :-)

Is there a more efficient way to keep track / create data of one variable all agents have?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood this correctly, you want each agent to remember the value of its variable my-charging-demand across all time. If so, the easiest way (but I don't know if it's more efficient) is to have the list as a turtle variable. So, modify your `turtles-own` to add another variable:

```
adopters-own
[ ....
  my-charging-demand
  my-charging-demand-series
]
```

And wherever you have the code for calculating demand, add the result to the list

```
ask adopters
[ ...
  set my-charging-demand ...
  set my-charging-demand lput my-charging-demand my-charging-demand-series
  ...
]
```

I can't imagine a plot with 500 lines is readable. The plot should do something like the average of my-charging-demand or the proportion of turtles with my-charging-demand greater than some threshold.

Comment: Thanks @JenB ! Good point. The plot is absolutely not readable, basically just a filled graph. I used this method since I could not think of a way to create data on an turtle-own variable for more than 100.000 ticks, but lists make total sense now :-) Do you think this would take less (processing) time, compared to the plotting method?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea of the efficiency of lists vs plots. I think it's a try it and see issue. I'd be interested in the answer too.

Comment: Here is a short test @JenB
Base case (with the 500 pens in one plot): 4:00 minutes lead to 1226 ticks
Base case (without the above mentioned plot): 4:00 minutes lead to 3682 ticks
Adapted model with your input (where agents update their own list): 4:00 minutes leads to 3673 ticks.

So it by far a faster way to keep track of agent-own variables. Now I just have to find out how to export all turtle-own lists in one CSV file, but that should not be too difficult I suppose.

Comment: glad it helped and thanks for the performance info. come back and ask a new question if you have trouble with the export